# 404 error on express + nodeJS, on a normal route

Tags: express, routes, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to create a web app as my first project, and I'm stuck on a little somethig.

I have the following code in the file routes/index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

/* GET all_hotels.pug page */
router.get('/all', function(req, res) {
  res.render('all_hotels', {title: 'All Hotels'});
})


module.exports = router;
```

And the following in app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The problem is that, when I access the path http://localhost:3000/all, I'm getting the default 404 error.
I've read all the documentation on express for this routes and I'm still not able to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the code below.
I think you are misunderstanding about route.
In app.js, this codeblock app.use('/', indexRouter); means that if(only get("/")){
go to index.js router} So the error occured.

-app.js

```
var allRouter = require('./routes/all');
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/all', allRouter);
```

create the routes/all.js and insert the code below
-routes/all.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();        
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('all_hotels', {title: 'All Hotels'});
})
module.exports = router;
```

I hope you will get the successful result. Thanks.

Comment: Sir, you're a genius !

Comment: Please approve the solution.